# using class as template type

Tags: c++, templates

! i'm working on a gun template,it should be like this:

```
template <Bullet>
class gun
{  



};
```

that Bullet is a class that will define in other file,my question is how i can use this bullet in gun as a type? how can i use a class as a template in other class? i want a little bit long explanation!
thanks...!

this is what i tried to do:

```
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define BulletWeapon1 100
#define BulletWeapon2 30
#define BulletWeapon3 50
enum Weapons
{
    Gun1,Gun2,Gun3

}CurrentWeapon;
template <class T=Bullet>
class Gun
{



};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only need the `Bullet` class inside `gun`, then you can just don't use a template:

```
class gun {
    Bullet x;
    // ...
};
```

otherwise, if you want to allow any class but provide a default class `Bullet`, you can use:

```
template <class T = Bullet>
class gun {
    T x;
    // ...
};
```

In particular, if you want to make sure that `T` is always a base class of `Bullet`, you can play around with *type traits* such as [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

---

On a side note, please try to avoid statements like `using namespace std;` and begin getting used to the `std::` prefix instead. It will save you some headaches when you'll have problems of multiple definitions or weird look ups.

Also, try to avoid `#define`s as well. This:

```
#define BulletWeapon1 100
#define BulletWeapon2 30
#define BulletWeapon3 50
```

can be converted to:

```
const int BulletWeapon1 = 100;
const int BulletWeapon2 = 30;
const int BulletWeapon3 = 50;
```

Finally notice that in C++11 you can use `enum class`es which are a little bit more type safe than simple `enum`s:

```
enum Weapons { Gun1,Gun2,Gun3 } CurrentWeapon;
```

can become:

```
enum class Weapons { Gun1, Gun2, Gun3 } CurrentWeapon = Weapons::Gun1;
```

Comment: Thanks...!
i define a X from T in my class but i can' use any of Bullet methods with it!
i define my template class like this:

Gun<Bullet> g;

so what is the problem now?!

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi "I define a X from T in my class but I can't use any of Bullet methods with it!" -- I'm struggling to understand. Can you post the non-working code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and click "Share!" and past the link to me?

Comment: #include "Bullet1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define BulletWeapon1 100
#define BulletWeapon2 30
#define BulletWeapon3 50
enum Weapons
{
 Gun1,Gun2,Gun3

}CurrentWeapon;
template <class T>
class Gun
{
};
int main()
{
 Gun<Bullet1> g;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi, it [compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ed90c8982e40898), what's the problem?

Comment: yeah it works! thanks so much!
just one more question:
for example Bullet have getSpeed() metchod,so how can in use this inside gun class?

Comment: @PeymanTahghighi, `x.getSpeed()`? It depends how you declared the `Bullet` member object.